# Dual boot: Windows 10 locks non-mounted drive

Tags: linux, windows-10, hard-drive, hibernate, dualboot

I have a dual boot setup of Windows 10 and MX-Linux. Windows and linux are running on separate partitions of my SSD and on top of that I have an extra HDD formatted as NTFS for backup and stuff.

I like to hibernate windows when changing back to linux, as I find it cumbersome to reboot it every time.
Plus I can keep games running and come back to them.

My problem is that windows puts a hibernation lock on the backup disk.
I only use windows for playing games, and I practically never need to access the backup disk from windows. Thus, I have disabled it completely, or tried to, on windows.
It's not mounted. I unassigned the drive letter from it under disk management. I have disabled it under the hardware tab in computer management.
Yet windows **still** puts a hibernation lock on the drive.

When I boot MXLinux back up, it's mounted as read-only, which is because of the lock. If I run ntfsfix on it and reboot linux, it mounts correctly. As read-write.

I have previously had a similar setup, where this problem did not occur.
The only difference from now being, that windows and linux were on their own separate physical drives and I would change between them using the BIOS boot menu, instead of GRUB. I don't see why that would make a difference.

Has anyone managed to overcome a problem like this before? Any suggestions? Beyond of course just not hibernating windows, which is the obvious solution.

Comment: “If I run ntfsfix on it and reboot linux, it mounts correctly. As read-write.”—You ___must not___ do this. Your resumed Windows could then either crash or, worse, corrupt critical NTFS data structures.

Comment: If you need to do what you want safely, give up the quarter century old strategy of dual boot and use Virtual Machines. That will do most of what you need except your host needs to be alive along with your working machine. Overall and all things considered, much better.

Comment: @DanielB I get what you're saying, but considering that the disk isn't even mounted on Windows, I doubt widows is going to actually perform any IO on the file system, which leads me to think removal of the hibernation lock with ntfsfix is really just a "formality". In this concrete scenario at least.

Comment: @John I can't imagine that would perform very well when running heavy duty video games under windows. I also expect the virtual machine overlay would hinder game engines from properly addressing and instructing the GPU.

Comment: I agree with you about performance. Make the high load machine the physical host machine and the lower load stuff to be virtual. Most users are unsuccessful trying to run dual boot. I gave up dual boot many years ago.

Comment: @KennethPetersen If the disk wasn't mounted it wouldn't be marked in use. Why risk it?